# Reuse detached floating IPs in OpenStack

Tags: openstack, floating-ip

Is there any command to get already created floating IPs from a pool and which aren't assigned anymore to any VM instance ?

That's my use case:

1. I create a floating IP and assign it to a VM with these commands:

   - `nova floating-ip create [MyPool]`
   - `nova add-floating-ip [MyVM] [created_ip]`
2. I shutdown MyVM and delete it
3. I do 1 and 2 in a loop and at a given time I use up all the available floating IPs in the pool and get the following error message:

   - `No more floating ips in pool MyPool`
4. Question: how to automatically reuse detached floating IPs that aren't in the floating pool anymore ?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't use nova to manage floating IPs only neutron.

`neutron floatingip-list`

But actually I ran `nova help` and there are options to get them ( I think now all the floating ip options with nova are deprecated). So you can try:

`nova floating-ip-list`

and then:

`nova floating-ip-associate`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. These commands give the list of existing IPs, even the associated ones. What I need is only one IP which isn't associated.

Comment: not sure about the command, but an easy python code will do the work.  
  Set A = openstack floating ip list, Set B = openstack floating ip list -- status "active" + openstack floating ip list --status "down".     Then A - B will give floating IPs not associated.

Answer (score 1):

```
openstack floating ip list -f json | jq  '.[] | select(.["Fixed IP Address"] == null ) | .["Floating IP Address"] '
```

This may work. I got this command from StackOverflow itself. Kindly check, if working, well and good, else Python code will do the magic required.