# Terraform Openstack attach pre-allocated Floating IPs to instance

Tags: ip, terraform, openstack, floating

I have a use case where I need to re-use detached Floating IPs.  Is there a way to do this in Terraform?  I've tried:

```
`
data "openstack_networking_floatingip_v2" "fips" {
   status = "DOWN"
}
`
```

to get a list of detached IPs, but I get an error saying there is more than one Floating IP (Which is true).

Is there a good way to get detached floating IPs as a data resource in terraform?  The alternative is passing an array of available IPs via a wrapper script with the command outlined here: [Reuse detached floating IPs in OpenStack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47974059/reuse-detached-floating-ips-in-openstack)

Comment: I'm guessing there is not a way to get detached floating IPs as a data resource in terraform, because the only data resource with "ip" in its name is `openstack_networking_floatingip_v2` and that only returns the `id` of the *one* found floating IP : https://registry.terraform.io/providers/terraform-provider-openstack/openstack/latest/docs/data-sources/networking_floatingip_v2

Comment: Yeah, there doesn't seem to be a openstack data resource that returns multiple IPs from what I can tell.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else that comes across this, here is I solved it for now:

I used the 'external' data resource to call the openstack cli to retrieve a comma seperated list of available ips.  The openstack cli command looks like this:

```
openstack floating ip list --status DOWN -f yaml -c "Floating IP Address"
```

In order to get the output in the format suitable for terraform's external data resource, I used a python script.  The script outputs a json object that looks like this: {ips = "ip.1.2.3,ip.4.5.6,ip.7.8.9"}

The external data resource in terraform looks like this:

```
data "external" ips {
    program = ["python", "<path-to-python-script>"]
}
```

From there I'm able to split the comma seperated string of ips in terraform and access the the ips as an array:

```
output available_ips {
    value = split(",", data.external.ips.result.ips)
}
```

It's definitely not elegant, I wish the openstack_networking_floatingip_v2 data resource would allow for this functionality, I'll look into opening an issue to get it added.

Comment: I used the same approach today, but the data source always retrieves the currently available floating ips, also when re-applying or detroying. So, when trying to destroy , for example, it will try to retrieve the available ones again, and maybe there will be none left and it will fail.